# How do I edit keyboard shortcuts in Nano?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Is there a way to edit the keyboard shortcuts in Nano?

I would like to change ***Move to next word*** from **Right** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) and **Left** (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>),
to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>.

According to this [thread on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235664/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-nano), one should be able to edit `/etc/nanorc`. However, on my OS X computer, that file is empty except for this line:

```
set nowrap
```

Assuming that this is the only file there is, how could I override the keyboard settings here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you install a more up-to-date version of nano, it has improved keyboard navigation. In nano 2.7, the move word shortcut is `ctrl+left/right`. So you might not even need to do keybindings if you are satisfied with `ctrl` instead of `alt`.

1. Install homebrew: https://brew.sh/
2. Install nano: `brew install nano`

If you really want `alt`, then keep reading.

1. If using Mac Terminal, you will need to enable the `Use Option as Meta key` setting. Otherwise the `alt` key won't work.
2. `/etc/nanorc` might be ignored, depending on the flags when your `nano` was compiled. You can use `~/.nanorc` instead, that will work for sure.
3. Add these lines to `~/.nanorc`. (It seems that `nanorc` does not allow left/right arrows for keybindings, so I chose `,` and `.` since they are the same keys as `<` and `>`.

   ```
   bind M-, prevword main
   bind M-. nextword main
   ```

Now `alt+,` and `alt+.` will move to prev/next words.

You can find the full list of commands here: https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.7/nanorc.5.html#REBINDING%20KEYS . (You may want to find the exact version of your `nano` if not v2.7).

Answer (score 4):

You can find a description of commands/settings allowed in `/etc/nanorc` by running `man nanorc`.

OS X 10.11-10.15 uses nano 2.0.6 which doesn't seem to support key rebindings.

However if you install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you can easily install a modern version of Nano with:

```
# brew install nano
... wait for install ...

# /usr/bin/nano --version
GNU nano version 2.0.6 (compiled 17:24:29, Jun  5 2020)

# /usr/local/bin/nano --version
GNU nano, version 5.3
```